# bash create file based on date?

Tags: bash, file-io

I'm trying to write a bash script to create/check for the existence of a file based on the date. Basically I want to have a direcotry of `todo_lists` inside of which are files with todays todo list. So every time I open the terminal (mac os 10.6.8) it would check to see if 6-29-11.txt or whatever based on

```
date "+%m%d%Y"
```

if it exists just `less` the contents of it and if it doesn't create one.

so I was wondering how to use that date formatted string as a file name and how to check string variables i.e.

```
[ -e date_string.txt ] && ...
```

How would I accomplish these things, I'm pretty new to bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATE=`date "+%m%d%Y"`
if [ -f "todo_lists/$DATE.txt" ]; then
  do stuff
fi
```

The backticks (`) means, run this command and return the output as a string

Comment: @pufos - I assume you mean, check if the file doesn't exist?, if so, then the syntax is `if [ ! -f "todo_lists/$DATE.txt" ]; then`

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose your Mac has bullets already inserted.

In short: you can make any file (default is $HOME/calendar) and you can enter one line reminder into it in the form like:

```
06/29<TAB>reminder for today
06/30<TAB>reminder for tomorrow
07/15<TAB>another one
```

and into your `$HOME/.profile` simple enter the `calendar` command.

After the above, every time you open a new terminal window, the `calendar` command will consult the calendar file for the today reminders and when found a reminder, will print out it...

you can include more different calendars (with namedays for example) and more...
check `man calendar`

---

and the answer to your qst is:

```
file="./todo/$(date "+%F").txt"
[ -f "$file" ] && {
        echo "My today reminders"
        cat "$file"
}
```

I suggest use the format "+%F" (2011-06-29) because you get a sorted list of files, when you do `ls` or so...

ps: use `$(command ....)` form instead of `command` (backticks) because you can easily nest `$(command $(another $(nexT)))` them. Backticks are deprecated in the current bash.

Comment: also exactly what i needed, just his came first